# Using a 8-Bit Color Correction Matrix for a 16-Bit Image

Tags: colors, type-conversion, camera-calibration

I have a Color-Correction Matrix for 8-Bit images but my camera gives back images in a 16-Bit format. Can I use the 8-Bit Color-Correction Matrix and multiply the values by 256 in the Color-Correction Matrix or is there a nonlinearity between these and if so which is it?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can multiply by 256.
Remember that applying the color matrix is just a matrix multiplication:

```
[R' G' B'] = [R G B] * M    (M is 3x3)
R' = R*M00 + G*M01 + B*M02
...
```

There is no "nonlinearity" here.
Remeber to shift the result by 16 bit after the multiplication to return to the 16 bit range (just like you shifted 8 bits with 8 bit images.)